# Displaying Total on MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I need to develop quite a serious database in access and start building up the Main Menu. 
So far I have (I have broken the problem down to a sample DB):
a) Set up a Table of Data (Table1) (Column 1 = Name, Column 2 = No of Staff (Numeric))
So my Data looks like this

```
Name      No of Staff
TestName1   1
TestName2   2
```

b) Created a Query (Table1 Query) to provide a Total of 3 as a sum total - this works as I get a total of 3.

c) I created a Form that I want as my Summary Form. 
and inserted a TextBox and placed the following formulae within the Expression Builder :

So I have the following : 
[image]

But the Form field yields a #Name?

Sorry for the novice question but I have read up quite a lot about this and this should work fine. I am confused why this simple little task is daunting.

Any help would be great. thxs in advance

Answer (score 2):

Two variants:

1. Set the query as datasource for your form and select the column with sum [Sum Of No of staff] as control source for your text field
2. set as Control Source for text field as

   `= Dlookup("[Sum Of No of staff]", "[Table1 Query]")`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure why ACCESS is not so "intuitive" in this respect, but coming from a VBA/VB.Net background the transition is understandably very different.